# One JFrame don't stop other frame's code

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, joptionpane

When the user clicks on the edit button a new frame is shown to them, and when the new frame is closed i want the refresh line to execute but problem is, the refresh line is executed before closing the new frame...I am using NetBeans for making UI.

```
//If user clicks on edit button new frame will be shown to him 
EditUserFrame editUserFrame = new EditUserFrame();
Iterator itr = userList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    user = (Users)itr.next();
    if((user.getF_name().equals(f_name) && user.getL_name().equals(l_name))){
        break;
    }
}//End of While Loop
editUserFrame.setUserObj(user);
editUserFrame.getExistingValues();
editUserFrame.setVisible(true);
//I want this line to be executed when the editUserFrame is closed..
RefreshUserTable();
```

I want new Frame like this is it possible to make form given in picture in JOPtionPane as suggested by you guys.

[image]

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the

```
'editUserFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
    //call your method from here
        RefreshUserTable();
    }
};'
```

hope this helps

Comment: there are a few other ways to do it, but for this occasion I think this is enough. Glad that I could be of some help.

Comment: @HaseebWali I notice that you have validation in your form, therefore using the JOptionPane OK_CANCEL is not the ideal solution because you do not have direct access to the OK button - it's possible to retrieve the OK button its extra work. in short Using the OK_CANCEL type of the JOptionPane is probably not the best solution.

Comment: Agree with you in this situation particularly

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a modal dialog of some kind.  Dialogs are designed to "halt" execution of the program at the point where they are displayed.

Check out [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

You can also use a `JOptionPane` to make your life easier, as they can be configured with different buttons/options relatively easily.  Check out [JOptionPane Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) for an overview

**Updated with Example**

[image]

```
public class TestOptionPane01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane01();
    }

    public TestOptionPane01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                
                FormPane formPane = new FormPane();
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                null, 
                                formPane, 
                                "Edit User", 
                                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                                -1);
                
                switch (result) {
                    
                    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                        System.out.println("You selected okay");
                        break;
                    case JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION:
                        System.out.println("You selected cancel");
                        break;
                    
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    public class FormPane extends JPanel {
    
        public FormPane() {
            
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Edit User"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JSeparator(), gbc);
            
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Fill all fields to edit user tecord"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridheight = 2;
            add(new JLabel("Select Image Icon"), gbc);
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridy += 2;
            add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Confirm Password"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Email Address"), gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("Maximum Image Size 32x32"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JButton("Select"), gbc);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridheight = 3;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            add(panel, gbc);
            gbc.gridy += 3;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(new JButton("Clear Image"), gbc);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: @Haseeb Wali use `JOptionPane`

Comment: @MadProgrammer A great Idea to deal with these sort of situation...Thanks for giving  your time.